# Is there any harm in force pushing to heroku all the time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, git, heroku

Frequently (especially with commits using `--amend`) I push to heroku using `git push heroku master --force`. I do this because I get an issue when trying to push without force..

issue:

```
o https://git.heroku.com/site.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/site.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I see no harm in it because my remote repository and local repository are fine. Am I wrong?

Comment: you should not need to force push unless you are trying to correct some really bad mistake, and even then there is a more correct way to fix it in git

Comment: Usually, a force push is used as a way to re-write the history on a remote. This could be by stripping commits or laying new commits onto an old Git object. How many people have write access to the Heroku app? Is it possible someone has pushed commits to the Heroku app but not to another shared remote (like GitHub) from which you've been doing your pulls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning happens because the commits are different and thus your repository cannot ensure data preservation, it is bad practice since it could lead to code data loss, as long as you know it won't, Heroku itself will not have a problem as all it does is take the code in the master branch and deploy it, regardless of previous states.

Comment: It's worth noting that when I asked this question, I did not understand that `--amend` effectively rewrote the local tree and if a remote repository was already updated, required a force push. This is expected behavior, and as this answer already said, it has absolutely no effect on heroku. It's simply an expectation with `--amend`.